# Issue with retaining user inputted values when resizing a dynamic array

Tags: c++, c

This is my attempt at creating a dynamic array that resizes after the user preallocates data for the array. I use a second index/counter in order to take on the value of the original counter.

MOST SPECIFICALLY,
How do I replace the random values in the computer with the user inputted values?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout <`enter code here`< "Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin  >> size;
    if (size <= 0) {
        cout << "Array size must be > 0" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    int *arr;
    arr = new int[size];

    int num = 0;
    int idx = 0, idx2 = 0;

    while (num != -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value to place into an array or -1 to exit: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (idx < size)
        {
            arr[idx++] = num;
        }
        else
        {
            idx2 = idx * 2;
            int *newArr = new int[size];
            memcpy(newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int));
            delete [] arr;
            newArr[idx++] = num;
            arr = newArr;

            /*
             int* temp = new int[length + added];
             memcpy(temp, array, length * sizeof(int));
             memcpy(temp + length, added_array, added * sizeof(int));
             delete[] array;
             array = temp;
             */
        }

    }

    for(int x = 0; x < idx; x++)
    {
        cout <<arr[x] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl  << "Reshaped Array of Size: "<< idx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, my output for an array of size 2 incorrectly displays the values that I entered (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 66, 55):

```
3
4
268848517
6
1397644077
55

Reshaped Array of Size: 6
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Please, don't tag as `C` a code that is clearly `C++` and cannot be compiled as `C` code.  Edit your question to eliminate `C` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code,

```
        else
        {
            idx2 = idx * 2;
            int *newArr = new int[size];               <<<<<<<<<<<<  bug
            memcpy(newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int));   <<<<<<<<<<<<
            delete [] arr;
            newArr[idx++] = num;
            arr = newArr;
```

There is a bug. You are creating int[] with the same "size". It should be "idx2".

+ memcpy()'s copy size should be changed accordingly (eg. idx)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this line

```
idx2 = idx * 2;
```

by

```
size = size * 2;
```

Don't need to use idx2 anymore.
It will work then.

Comment: Agreed, but I would do `int *newArr = new int[2 * size]; memcpy(newArr, arr, 2 * size * sizeof(int));` and move `size = size * 2;` below `arr = newArr;` with the `delete` and `newArr[idx++] = num;` following. It just prevents updating `size` until after the allocation of `newArr` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

While your biggest problem is multiplying `idx2 = idx * 2` instead of multiplying `size` by two, you may want to reorder your conditional tests to eliminate the three part test. All you need to do is check if `num == -1` and if so, `break`, otherwise just text if `idx == size` and if so, reallocate, e.g.

```
    while (num != -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value to place into an array or -1 to exit: ";
        cin >> num;

        if (num == -1)
            break;
        else if (idx == size) {
            int *newArr = new int[2 * size];
            memcpy(newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int));
            delete [] arr;
            arr = newArr;
            size *= 2;
        }
        arr[idx++] = num;
    }
```

(unless you `break;` the loop, you will always assign `arr[idx++] = num;`)

Don't forget to free the memory you allocate when you are done with it, e.g.

```
    delete [] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Note, you should always validate your input, e.g.

```
    if (!(cin >> num)) {
        cerr << "error: invalid integer value.\n";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you David for your help

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Coding is as much an art as it is a science. Anyone can write code that will "work", but learning to write it so it efficiently flows like poetry instead of looking like splattered paint in the editor window is the goal.